# Do EU citizens need travel insurance when visiting Israel?

Tags: insurance, israel

**Do EU citizens need travel insurance when visiting Israel?**

The time between entry and exit is 10 days.

Country of departure: Bulgaria

Citizenship: EU

Comment: I do not know, but many countries requires health insurance. Are you sure you are not confusing both insurances? (one it is purely private, the other could be public [depending on the countries])

Comment: UK travel advice states “ Healthcare in Israel is not free and medical treatment can be expensive. Hospitals will insist on payment and may take legal action to delay departure until bills are met. Make sure you have adequate travel health insurance and accessible funds to cover the cost of any medical treatment abroad and repatriation.” While specifically aimed at UK citizens it seems likely that advice would apply EU-wide.

Comment: Social Security Agreements exist with Israel which may not cover everything, so a private travel insurance is advised.

Comment: So according to Traveller's comment it is not a legal requirement, but you can get yourself into very bad trouble if you have an accident while on holiday in Israel. Travel companies might refuse to accept you without travel insurance because they don't want to have to cope with such trouble.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this travel insurance site](https://www.insuremytrip.com/destinations/israel-travel-insurance/), which was last updated this August, travel insurance is not required by the nation of Israel for EU citizens, but of course it is usually highly recommended regardless of where you are travelling.

> Consequently, we are frequently asked whether travel insurance is required for trips to Israel. The answer is no.
>
> [...]
>
> Israel is not part of the Schengen zone, so travel insurance does not need to be Schengen visa-compliant when traveling there. However, if Israel is but one stop and other stops on your trip include countries that are part of the Schengen area, you may still need to purchase a [Schengen visa-compliant plan](https://www.insuremytrip.com/travel-insurance-plans/schengen-visa/). Only citizens of [certain countries](https://www.schengenvisainfo.com/who-needs-schengen-visa/) are required to obtain Schengen visas when visiting any of the 26 member countries.

Many sites, including government sites like [gov.uk](https://www.gov.uk/foreign-travel-advice/israel/health), specifically note that health care in Israel is very expensive and you will be required to pay for your bills when you leave the country.

> Hospitals will insist on payment and may take legal action to delay departure until bills are met. Make sure you have adequate travel health insurance and accessible funds to cover the cost of any medical treatment abroad and repatriation.

So although not technically required by the Israeli government for EU citizens, it is very highly advisable that you do purchase insurance.